# How to populate array with numbers based on odds?

Tags: javascript, probability

I recently saw a roulette wheel of sorts which contained the following possible numbers. 1, 2, 9, 16, 24, 49j and 49f. Each number has odds of itself over 1. So the odds of rolling a 2 are 2/1 and a 9 is 9/1. I thought it would be a fun (and simple) exercise to populate an array with the right amount of each type of number but it's proved anything but. My first idea was to build a name/value array to hold each numbers odds and then a second one to hold a counter value.

```
let numbers = {
"1": "1",
"2": "2",
"9": "9",
"16": "16",
"24": "24",
"49f": "49",
"49j": "49"
};
let counter = {
"1": "0",
"2": "0",
"9": "0",
"16": "0",
"24": "0",
"49f": "0",
"49j": "0"
};
let tc = {
"1": "0",
"2": "0",
"9": "0",
"16": "0",
"24": "0",
"49f": "0",
"49j": "0"
};
```

That last one tc is just to tally how many of each number is in the final array and confirm my mathematical genius. So from here it should be a simple matter of looping 50 times and looping through each number, incrementing its counter by 1 and when the counter value equals the odds value, push that number into the array and reset its counter to 0. So each iteration I should get a 1 and every 3rd iteration I should get a 2 and so on.

```
var wheel = [];

function load_numbers( ) {
for(let number in numbers) {
  var count = parseInt(counter[number], 10);
  var odd = parseInt(numbers[number], 10);
  var t = parseInt(tc[number], 10);
  count++;
  if (count == odd) {
    wheel.push(number);
    count = 0;
    t++; tc[number] = t; 
  }
  counter[number] = count;
}
}

function load_wheel( ) {
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  load_numbers();
}

for(let mc in tc) {
    document.write(mc + ": " + tc[mc] + " of " + wheel.length + " <br>");
}
}
```

However that code produces the following

```
1: 50 of 87
2: 25 of 87
9: 5 of 87
16: 3 of 87
24: 2 of 87
49f: 1 of 87
49j: 1 of 87
```

These odds are clearly wrong but I can't see what's wrong with the method, I've tried doubling the odds and looping 100 times, still wrong. Setting a breakpoint after 49j == 1 also gives me these odds. In desperation I tried calculating the percentage of each numbers odds and adding them together (ie 1 = 50%, 2 = 33%) and that procedure keeps giving me 108%! So at this point I have to conclude I've been wrong about math my whole life or the Casino is pulling a fast one! Or is there something I'm overlooking?